# Why doesn't foreach and ginv work together in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying parallel implementation in R. First, I tried this naive example, which worked fine on my server.

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach(i=1:3) %dopar% sqrt(i)
```

I was trying to use `ginv` along with foreach. But R throws up an error saying.

**Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "ginv""**

Here is a simple reproducible example:

```
foreach (i = 1:50) %dopar% {
  ginv(matrix(rexp(10000, rate=.01), ncol=100))

}
```

I am sure I must be missing something. Can you please help? Thank you!

Comment: Please search for a solution on SO before posting. This has been answered several times, as well as the other question you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ginv()` function comes from a package (probably `MASS`, but there are other versions on CRAN too) which has not been loaded on the worker machines. Either use the full name (e. g.  `MASS::ginv` or tell `foreach` to load the package, e. g.

```
foreach(..., .packages = "MASS") ...
```